# Could not find com_facebook_androi.apk?

Tags: android, facebook

I have downloaded the android API and added the reference to my Sample application. When i run the application i get the error : " Could not find com_facebook_android.apk!". And my Facebook application does not appear. Where am i doing wrong. Please guide me in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give enough information about what you are trying to do, but I think the answer to this question may help you: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7258394/i-get-a-could-not-find-com-facebook-android-apk-error-when-i-run-my-android-pr/7265972#7265972

At least it sounds like the same problem you have.